# How to compile Boost as a dynamic library with static stdc++ and gcc links on Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, boost, b2

I am looking to compile Boost on Linux as a shared library (so `.\b2 install link=shared`) but with a static link to libstdc++ and libgcc.

Without any modifications to the above command, I naturally see a dynamic link to those two libraries:

```
 ldd libboost_filesystem.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffebd5ef000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2f8330d000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2f832f2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2f832cf000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2f830dd000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2f82f8e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2f83521000)
```

The linker flags in question that would statically link gcc and stdc++ are `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++`. I have used them in with CMake projects and they work as expected (I just add during configuration `-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"`).

With the Boost b2 install script, I've throwing those flags everywhere to hedge my bets:

```
./b2 install cxxflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" cflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" linkflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"
```

to no avail.

I also tried:

```
./b2 install gcc/linkflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" gcc/cxxflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" gcc/cflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"
```

and

```
./b2 install gcc/linkflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" gcc/cxxflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" gcc/cflags="-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" gcc/link=static
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm obviously missing something about those particular flags. How can I properly use those flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` flags as `linkflags`

First download and extract the Boost source files then go to the Boost directory and run `./bootstrap.sh` then modify the project-config.json file to add this at the end `using gcc : : : <linkflags>-static-libgcc <linkflags>-static-libstdc++ ;`

Now you can build and install the Boost libraries with this command `./b2 install link=shared`